# What should handle drag & drop of UIViewController within UIView?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I have a UIView that acts as a container for widgets (UIViewController subclass). I was able to add simple UIButtons to the UIView container and get the drag/drop functionality working, but I'm running into issues when I attempt to drag/drop a UIButton from a Widget that was added to the UIView container. When I attempt to interact with the button, nothing happens other than the default touch behavior.

Should I be using a delegate in this scenario, telling my Widget's button that the UIView container will be the one handling the drag/drop?

I'm adding the widget in the container's ViewController with the following:

```
    // Widget is a UIViewController subclass, WidgetTestViewController is a Widget subclass
    Widget *testWidget = [[WidgetTestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WidgetTest" bundle:nil];

    [testWidget.widgetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(widgetDrag:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

    [containerView addSubview:testWidget.view];
    testWidget.view.frame = frame;
```

I'm handling the drag in the container's ViewController through this function:

```
- (IBAction)widgetDrag:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:containerView];
    UIControl *control = sender;
    control.center = point;
}
```